# TradeMark(TM) sign appears as a question mark on device

Tags: android, ascii

I'm displaying the trademark sign(™) appended to a text as a title of dialog box. It is working fine in emulator. But when I'm running the same in device then it displays as a question mark(?). Any ideas why it is happening and how to avoid that?

Comment: make sure your page is encoded in UTF-8 .

Comment: hope this helps you out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106617/can-we-add-subscript-for-android-app-launcher-name

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDITED**

You can do this:

```
<string name="trademark_symbol">&#8482;</string>
<string name="app_name">My Application &#8482;</string>
```

Try this in your layout editor and you will see the symbol.