# How to put special trade character in Android string.xml

Tags: android, xml

I need to put "TM" (trademark) character in my string.xml, how I should do that ?

```
<string name="snap_recipesnap_button">RecipeSnap\&trade;</string>
```

I have sth like this but it doesn't work

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211783/trademarktm-sign-appears-as-a-question-mark-on-device)... please search first before posting questions

Comment: I did, but haven't found anything. Thanks

Comment: See this post on stack-overflow :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613884/how-do-i-insert-special-characters-as-text-in-xml-editor-for-android

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May this help you:

```
<string name="snap_recipesnap_button">RecipeSnap &#8482;</string>
```